# how to curl file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl

I have curl code recived a image file

```
curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKENS' https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/8595925133330/content -o image.png
```

how to get the file using python?

Comment: use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)? In particular, use `requests.get(<URL>, ...)`.

Comment: already do that, but in case this use tokens

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers - try that, and if you can't get it to work, _show us what you've tried_ and someone should be able to help you.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser i do this `r = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)` how i get image file or json?

Comment: Put the _actual code_ in your _question_, including what you set `headers` to. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKENS' https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/8595925133330/content -o image.png
```

Comparable Python Script should be like below:

```
import requests
endpoint = "https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/8595925133330/content"
headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer TOKENS"}

r = requests.post(endpoint,headers=headers)
open('image.png', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: how about if this file not image file, i just change ext?

Comment: If it is binary, then you just change the ext., If it is text then you may change the write mode to 'w' and the ext. of the filename